# Android RTF editor

Tags: android, text-editor, rtf

For many years I have used WordPad to make notes about almost everything, and now have hundreds of RTF files on my PC. I can access these (via cloud backup) with a tablet but cannot view/edit these files.

Is there a free, lightweight Android editor which can view and preferably edit RTFs?

Comment: What's wrong with this stuff? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-documents-in-rtf-file-type

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to browse my [list of office apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office). Most of them won't be "lightweight", but many of them support RTF.